# TextArea is not updating while zip extraction

Tags: multithreading, javafx, task

I am working on a JavaFx application, there i have a script that extract a zip followed by some other operation like updating files etc.

I want to have a textArea that displays whats going on in background, like "Zip extracting...", "Updating xyz file" etc.

Till now i have tried following way:

```
            MyTask<String> task;
                task = new MyTask<String>() {
                    @Override
                    protected String call() throws Exception {

                        File path = new File(exportTo.getAbsolutePath());
                        updateMessage("Extracting modular app to target directory...");
                        patcher.unZip(appPath.getAbsolutePath(), path.getAbsolutePath());

                        if (path.exists()) {
                            AppInfo info = getAppInfo();
                            patcher.patchAndroid(info, resourceZip, new File(path.getAbsolutePath() + "/" + appPath.getName().substring(0, appPath.getName().lastIndexOf("."))), this);
                            showOkAlert("Build completed!");
                        } else {
                            showOkAlert("Modular app folder not found");
                        }
                        return "";
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void updateProgress(double workDone, double max) {
                        patcher.reportLogs(message);
                    }

                    private String message;

                    @Override
                    public void updateMessage(final String message) {

                        Platform.runLater(() -> patcher.reportLogs(message));

                        this.message = message;
                        //updateProgress(0, 0);
                    }
                };
                task.run();
```

MyTask class

```
abstract class MyTask<T> extends Task<T> {

    abstract public void updateMessage(String message);
}
```

I have tried using updateProgress method, Platform.runLater() but nothing is working.

All the message i printed in textArea are printed after all operation is done.

Please help.

Comment: You need to run your `Task` on a new thread, see e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/concurrency.htm

Comment: @sillyfly Thanks alot. Solved my problem.

Comment: Then consider deleting your question ...

Comment: @GhostCat I know why are you concerned about that. But what if someone else run into this problem? I spent plenty of time figuring out what is the problem, at last i had to post this question. I did not post this question to get upvotes. I hope you will understand. And I have just started working with JavaFX since last tree days.

Comment: I got that; but not being a JavaFx expert, my first thought was: something wrong about threading here ... of course, you can choose to keep the question, but then I would recommend A) that you improve your question a bit, like putting a real  [mcve] in there ... and that you or @sillyfly put up an answer, with working code for that problem. Feel free to drop me a note when you are done; I never mind upvoting good content ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @sillyfly Please answer this question for future readers. You deserve upvotes for saving my hours and may be for others also in future.

Comment: Aside: note that `Task` already has an `updateMessage(String message)` method, and you probably should not override it, or the `updateProgress(...)`, method here. Instead, use the existing `updateMessage` method, and either register a listener or bind to the task's `messageProperty()`.

Comment: @James_D Task doesn't have an updateMessage() method i have checked it.

Comment: @chandil03 [Check again](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateMessage-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As javadoc for [Task](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html) states you need to manually create a `Thread` to execute your `Task`:

```
     Thread th = new Thread(task);
     th.start();
```

Currently your `task` is being run on Application UI thread and blocks UI updates.